# Is it possible to upload a file as a blob of data using filepicker.io, instead of using the file selection modal?

Tags: filepicker.io

I have this problem:

I want to make an interface where the user can drag and drop file uploads.  Filepicker.io provides an easy solution to this in the form of `filepicker.makeDropPane`.  However, this feature does not support parallel uploads without the callbacks getting confused.

So I would like to write my own drag/drop interface using standard html5 listeners, and make a direct api upload call to filepicker.io with the actual file data in string form.  This way I can write the management of parallel uploads on my own.

Does filepicker.io have an api call that would allow me to do this?  I only see these two things:

1) File selection modal
2) Auto drag-drop features

I don't see a way to simply upload a file directly from file data.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of the filepicker.store() command, which accepts a DOM file object. For example:

```
var input = document.getElementById("store-input");
filepicker.store(input, function(FPFile){/*your code here*/});
```

More details available at https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#store

Comment: This doesn't work because it requires an <input>. Drag/drop does not use <input>s - you listen for drop events which have data transfer files. HTML does not allow you to set the value of <input>s to these files (or anything else) for security reasons.

Comment: Yes, I should have clarified that if you take the HTML5 File object (from the e.dataTransfer.files array) it will work as well